# How to get rid of the "Incompatible pointer types" warning?

Tags: objective-c, constructor, initialization

I have this simple Shape class:

Shape.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface Shape : NSObject

-(id)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color;
+(instancetype)shapeWithColor:(UIColor *)color;

@end
```

and Shape.m

```
#import "Shape.h"

@interface Shape ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *color;

@end


@implementation Shape

-(id)init
{
    return [self initWithColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
}

-(id)initWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    self = [super init];

    if (self)
    {
        _color = color;
    }

    return self;
}

+(instancetype)shapeWithColor:(UIColor *)color
{
    return [[self alloc] initWithColor:color]; // I get the warning here
}

@end
```

In the convenience constructor's return statement, I'm getting the following warning:

> Incompatible pointer types sending 'UIColor *' to parameter of type
>   'CIColor *'

What am I doing wrong here? I know I can write `return [[Shape alloc] initWithColor:color];` but in that case I will cause problems to my subclasses if I use `Shape` instead of `self`, right?

Comment: Your code looks correct. If you CMD-click on `initWithColor:` where does it point to?

Comment: Probably, bot related to the issue, but you can use `instancetype` on the `init` methods too. Also is this the actual code? Did you omit anything?

Comment: @GabrielePetronella: `instancetype` is actually inferred for `init...`

Comment: @GabrielePetronella cmd+click seems to work correctly -- it detects 3 occurrences of -initWithColor in Shape, CIImage and CIColor. And yes, this is the actual code I'm using in a newly created project.

Comment: @JoshCaswell yes, you are right. Still I think is nicer to explicitly use it in any initializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compiler is confused since `initWithColor:` is also a method of `CIImage`, defined as

```
- (id)initWithColor:(CIColor *)color;
```

You can easily verify this by cmd-clicking on the method name. You will get the following dropdown, indicating that multiple declarations matching that name exist

[image]

You can either change the name or add an explicit cast:

```
return [(Shape *)[self alloc] initWithColor:color];
```

The cast will provide enough information for the compiler to correctly type check the method parameters, and it won't affect the possibility for subclassing.

To further clarify the last concept, I'd like to stress the fact that casting **doesn't** change the object type at runtime. It's just a compiler hint.

```
return [[Shape alloc] init];         // always  returns an object of type Shape
return (Shape *)[[self alloc] init]; // the actual type depends on what self is,
                                     // but the compiler will typecheck against
                                     // Shape
```

Comment: OK, I could change the name, but this shouldn't be the case, right? Plus, I just added two more initializers for testing, `-(id)initWithString:(NSString *)string;` and `+(instancetype)shapeWithString:(NSString *)string;`. For these two, I get no compiler warnings..

Comment: And if I do use casting, then my subclasses will only receive `Shape` objects, which is not correct.

Comment: You get no warnings since there's no type mismatch in that case.

Comment: @Irene casting doesn't change the object type. It's just a compiler hint. You're subclasses will be just fine.

Comment: @Irene, no problem. I also added a note about casting.