# How to conform to two protocols defining a method with the same name and different signature?

Tags: ios, objective-c, gamekit, overloading

I am using iOS7's new feature, MultipeerConnectivity. It comes with a function `didChangeState:`

in ViewController.h,

```
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h>
#import <MultipeerConnectivity/MultipeerConnectivity.h>
@interface ViewController : UIViewController <GKPeerPickerControllerDelegate, GKSessionDelegate, MCBrowserViewControllerDelegate, MCSessionDelegate>
```

in ViewController.m,
both of the following methods are required to implement:

```
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state{ ...... }
```

// which the name is duplicate to iOS6 Gamekit function:

```
- (void)session:(GKSession *)session peer:(NSString *)peerID didChangeState:(GKPeerConnectionState)state { ...... }
```

since iOS does not support function overloading, how should I include both functions in the same program? It is failed to compile. Error: Duplicate declaration of method 'session:peer:didChangeState:' I am using latest XCode 5.0.1.

Comment: Unless these are functions in the same class hierarchy, they will not conflict.

Comment: This is the problem: Duplicate declaration of method 'session:peer:didChangeState:' Build Failed.

Comment: It's surely not because of the problem you mentioned in the question, show how you import those two methods.

Comment: in ViewController.h
#import <GameKit/GameKit.h> 
#import <MultipeerConnectivity/MultipeerConnectivity.h>
in ViewController.m, both Gamekit and MultipeerConnectivity's session:peer:didChangeState implemented. It is failed to compile error.

Comment: I cannot reproduce the issue, there's something else you are omitting that is causing it

Comment: Likely you have some sort of circular include problem.  Or perhaps on of the definitions is in precompiled headers.

Comment: @user2957392 please edit the question and include the **actual** code you are using to import the frameworks.

Comment: It is not circular problem. Both methods import from the 2 different classes, Gamekit (GKPublicProtocols.h) and MultipeerConnectivity (MCSession.h) which both are required to implement.

Answer (score 9):

The issue is not coming from importing the two frameworks, but from your class conforming to both `GKSessionDelegate` and `MCSessionDelegate`. **Implementing** those two methods in the same class is something you cannot do since they have the same name.

You will have to use two different classes, one conforming to `GKSessionDelegate` and one to  `MCSessionDelegate`.

---

#### Original answer

Just go ahead and include them.

Importing two classes defining a method with the same name is by no means method overloading.

Overloading occurs when defining multiple methods with the same name but different signature on the same class hierarchy, which is not the case here (and it will never be, since it's forbidden in Objective-C)

---

The only issue you might have is the compiler not being able to correctly type check when you don't provide enough information.

For instance if you do

```
id anObject = //... retrieve the object
[anObject session:aSession peer:anId didChangeState:aState]
```

the compiler will warn you that he's not able to understand which of the two methods you are calling, since there's no information on the type. A simple cast will quiet the compiler.

At runtime, though, you won't have issues, since the type will be dynamically resolved.

As an example, you can refer to this recent question: [How to get rid of the "Incompatible pointer types" warning?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19757350/how-to-get-rid-of-the-incompatible-pointer-types-warning/19757849#19757849)

Comment: The the Objective C runtime does not distinguish between `NSString` and any other type. Signatures that differ only by object type are not allowed.

Comment: @Neal I know. Which part of my answer says something different?

Comment: I did not see the comment on the question. I assumed, incorrectly, that you were advising him that it was ok to put both in the same class and simply suppress or ignore the warning. My apologies. I would add that if the compiler is warning you, there is an issue that should be fixed.

Comment: Got it, but I disagree on your last statement. The compiler not being able to disambiguate is not necessarily symptom of an issue.

Comment: @GabrielePetronella Actually, it is a sign of ambiguity, which the compiler -- especially the ARC compiler -- is moving away from allowing.  If `anObject` is from MultiPeerConnectivity, but the GameKit is invoking that method, then... **BOOM**.

Comment: @bbum Agreed. My point is simply that if you know what you are doing, you can look at the warning and decide to ignore it and use a cast.

Comment: I am using ARC compiler, which is failed to compile, not just a runtime or type casting problem.

Comment: @user2957392, read my updated answer. You cannot implement those two delegate methods in the same class.

Comment: Actually, for delegate methods, one could have a common (single) implementation for both.  But to do it you'd probably have to omit one protocol in the @interface statement and explicitly cast to the appropriate protocol when setting the delegate pointer.  And, of course, there would be no way to have two distinct implementations within the single class.

Comment: @HotLicks This would work provided that the two methods share both name and signature, which is not che case.

Comment: They don't have to share signature (parm type info), only name.  But of course, the parm types are diverse enough that it would be a bit of a coding nightmare to separate them into two distinct code paths where required, based on parm types.  But theoretically doable.

Comment: @HotLicks gave me a big hint above. I re-write the ViewController.m as:

#pragma mark -
@@implementation ViewController (MCSessionDelegate)
- (void)session:(MCSession *)session peer:(MCPeerID *)peerID   didChangeState:(MCSessionState)state 
{
}
@@end

the program is able to compile and seems work as expected.

Comment: @HotLicks agreed. Theoretically doable, but terrible in practice.

Comment: @user2957392, also that specific GK delegate method is deprecated.